# Phone calls blocking in Android

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there any way to block all incoming calls and messages for a while, or is it possible to put my mobile in silent mode programmatically?

Comment: With an airplane mode maybe : `Settings.System.putInt(
      getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my internet should work at the same time

Comment: Then `AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int ringerMode = audiomanage.getRingerMode();
audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);` and put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>` in the `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

For put mobile in silent mode pragmatically you have to do like this :

```
AudioManager am;
am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//For Silent mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

//For Vibrate mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```